# Firestore rule auth based document access doesnt work

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a Firestore database and a collection to which I want to set rule to access.
I am using following rule but its not working

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }

  // other rules go here...

  }
}
```

But request.auth != null doesnt work at all , not sure whats wrong , I only have one collection root of the database called "events".

Any help appreciated.

Here is the code to access the events from collection

```js
const loadMultiEventData = async () => {

        setMessageState(true)    
        var tempArray = []
        var eventId = []
        var db = firebase.firestore();
        const eventsRef = await db.collection("events").get() 
        
        eventsRef.forEach((doc) => {
            eventId.push(doc.id)
            console.log('event:'+doc.id)
        })   
        var eventItem = []
        for(var i = 0; i< eventId.length; i++) {
            const itemsRef = await db.collection("events").doc(eventId[i]).collection('eventItems').get()
            itemsRef.forEach((item) => {
                console.log('event item:'+item.id)
                var item = {
                    id:eventId[i],
                    eventItemId:item.id
                }
                eventItem.push(item)
            })
        }

        var allEvents = []

        var date = new Date()
        date -= (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        console.log('backdate:' + date)
        for(var i = 0; i < eventItem.length; i++) {
            const eItem = eventItem[i]
            
            const doc = await db.collection("events").doc(eItem.id).collection('eventItems').doc(eItem.eventItemId).get()

            var eventDate = doc.data()['date'].toDate()
            console.log(eventDate)
            
            if(eventDate.getTime() > date) {

                var item = {
                    userId:eItem.id,
                    userData:doc.data()['userData'],
                    name:doc.data()['name'],
                    location:doc.data()['location'],
                    eventItemId:doc.id,
                }
                allEvents.push(item)
            }
        }
        setMessageState(false)
        setMultiEventData(allEvents)
        
    }
    const searchEvent = (event) => {
        multiEventData.forEach((eventItem) => {
            var item = eventItem
            if(item.name.includes(event) === true) {
                loadEventData(item.eventItemId,item.userId) 
                setSelectedEvent(item) 
            }
        })
    }
```

Also in another function I am logging in too.

```
 useEffect(() => {
   
    tempAuth();
    loadMultiEventData()
},[]);
```

Comment: Security rules by themselves don't do anything.  They are only triggered when a client app accesses the database.  Please edit the question to show that app code, and explain why the rule isn't working the way you expect for that.  If your rule requires auth, your code should also demonstrate that a user is definitely signed in with Firebase Auth at the time of the query.

Comment: @DougStevenson please check the code added , all I want is any user logged in the app should be able to access all the collections. Simple .

Comment: We still can't tell from your code here if a user is actually signed using Firebase Auth in at the time of the query, which is absolutely required by your rules.  There is also no error handling that suggests any queries are failing.  Please edit the question to improve the code in these respect.  If you add logging or error handling, show the output of that.

Comment: @DougStevenson you see the useEffect function ? at the bottom of question and code ? It calls tempAuth and after that loadMultiEventData, if you are saying just before the query I should be doing auth then I didn't know that , nowhere firebase docs explicitly say anything about this.

Comment: @DougStevenson one thing , I understand that I need to do auth first and then perform operation , but what happens when user goes to other page ? Thats what is happening now .

Answer (score 2):

*IF* the security rules had anything to do with it, you would be getting "permission denied" errors.  Do you catch your errors?

What I *can* see immediately is the line

```
const itemsRef = await db.collection("events").doc(eventId[i]).collection('eventItems').get()
```

BUT BUT BUT .collection.get() DOES NOT RETURN AN ARRAY.  It returns a QuerySnapshot, which has a PROPERTY .docs which is an array of QueryDocumentSnapshots.

Comment: Basically i dont know what you are trying to say but above code is working code when rules are set to relaxed / test mode .